# Two process bind and listen on the same address and port, but how to make sure both of them can receive the incoming message?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp

I have a server application, part of its code like this:

```
socket = socket(...); // create a socket
setsockopt(RE_USEADDR); // set the socket option RE_USEADDR
bind(socket, 127.0.0.1, 8080); // bind the socket to the IP address and Port
listen(); // listen
```

Here is the question:

1. I launch the server application twice, on the same machine, same user.
   Both of them can work well.
2. Launch the client application, which connects to `127.0.0.1:8080`
3. Send some contents to the server.
   However only one of the server application can receive the message from client.

Is there anyway to make sure the two server applications all receive the message from client.
If there is, please explain how and why in TCP and UDP.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have a front end server application that forwards the message to the two other server applications.

Comment: How can you launch 2 servers that listen on the same port? You should get some kind of "error, address already in use". Or maybe I don't understand `RE_USEADDR` option ...

Comment: @pptaszni Yes, you can if you use the RE_USEADDR option for the socket

Comment: Yes, true. However, apparently the behavior of 2 sockets bound to the same address is non-deterministic, according to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-so-reuseaddr-and-so-exclusiveaddruse). They also mention the possibility to use multicast

Comment: which OS are you using ?

Comment: That's not what SO_REUSEADDR does.  q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/4641116 ... is RE_USEADDR the same as SO_REUSEADDR?

Comment: @Eljay yes, SO_REUSEADDR, I just write a sample code that maybe incorrect and try to explain what i want to know.

Comment: @Cyril Jouve Win10 home

Comment: @pptaszni Yes, I want to use the multicast, but does that only work for UDP?

Comment: @Kuroto You can't have a TCP client socket connected to multiple TCP servers at a time, let alone send a message to multiple TCP servers simultaneously. You would need multiple TCP connections for that. There is no point in binding multiple TCP servers to the same local IP/Port, except maybe for load balancing. And there is no multicast in TCP

Comment: You can also look into multicast, if you are looking to have multiple processes listen on the same port.